# Prune filename with digits with "find" in OSX and GNU

Tags: regex, macos, unix

I am trying to make a search on a file and prune similar ones with digits in the name

- myfile.txt

from

- myfile_00_04_version.txt
- myfile_00.txt

.

```
find -E . -iregex ".*myfile.*([^0-9]{1,})\.txt"
```

gets rid of myfile_00.txt, but not of myfile_00_04_version.txt

I tried both OSX find and GNU find, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `.*` lets the pattern match any chars in between `myfile` and a non-digit followed with `.txt`. You need to remove it, and use

```
.*myfile[^0-9/]{1,}\.txt
```

Note that `[^0-9/]` will match any char but a digit and `/` (to stay within a file name).

Or, to make sure the file name starts with `myfile`:

```
(.*/)?myfile[^0-9/]{1,}\.txt
```

where `(.*/)?` matches an optional substring, from the start of the path up to the last `/`.