# regex [^/] for sorting out files

Tags: regex

I was advised `[^/]` before file extension helps sort out files.

```
find -E . -type f -maxdepth 1 -regex "^.*[^/].*ansi.*[^/]\.py" -exec basename {} \;
```

I understand the first `[^/]`. But why does one need the second one, if the only thing after is the file extension? And why does it work this way, I would suppose it should not have found the file?

Comment: Can you add samples? I would also expect the regex not to match any file expect those that look like `something.ansi.X.py` (or `somethingansissipy` since `.` will match any character). I also fail to see how that would help with sorting, what kind of sort order are you looking for?

Comment: `ansi.*[^/]\.py` will match things like `ansi-something.py` but not `ansi-something/.py`. But the whole regex looks a bit weird, especially the `.*[^/].*` part (which *will* match anything containing *any* non-slash character, even if it contains slashes). [What’s this trying to do?](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: The advice seems misdirected, at least as applied here. Do you have a link to where this advice came from?

Comment: The XCode tools were automatically update after I had asked this question, so it is all working the way it is 1. the search result to be found: text_to_ansi_symbols.py. This kind of expression appeared when I could not find the single file Carolingian_history_01.txt with find -E . -type f -maxdepth 1 -iregex ".*Car.*hist.*[0-9]\.txt" for some reason I do not entirely understand (not I think it is a bug).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984483/prune-filename-with-digits-with-find-in-osx-and-gnu/52984623#52984623